# Azure Functions Custom dlls for Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-lake

I get the following error when trying to import some custom dlls for the Azure Data Lake SDK in my .csx file. The error is below:

```
Function started (Id=1d6d553e-0ef5-45f2-bffb-dea4ad869424)

Function compilation error

D:\home\site\wwwroot\bigdataanalytics-azurefunction\ingestservices\NewsService.csx(2,1): warning AF006: The reference '..\bin\Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll' is invalid. If you are attempting to add a framework reference, please remove the '.dll' file extension.

D:\home\site\wwwroot\bigdataanalytics-azurefunction\ingestservices\NewsService.csx(2,1): error CS0006: Metadata file '..\bin\Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll' could not be found

D:\home\site\wwwroot\bigdataanalytics-azurefunction\ingestservices\NewsService.csx(3,1): error CS0006: Metadata file '..\bin\Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.dll' could not be found

D:\home\site\wwwroot\bigdataanalytics-azurefunction\ingestservices\NewsService.csx(4,1): error CS0006: Metadata file '..\bin\Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.dll' could not be found
```

My Project structure is the following:

[image]

project.json configuration:

```
{
    "frameworks": {
        "net45": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime": "2.3.2",
                "Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure": "3.3.2",
                "Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store": "1.0.4"
            }
        },
        "net46": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
                "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json": "4.3.0",
                "System.Net.Requests": "4.3.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your referenced CSX files are in a sub folder, the references are relative to the function folder, so you don't want to use `#r "..\bin\assembly.dll"`, but instead, use just `#r "assembly.dll"`.

For your NuGet packages, all references you intend to use must be under the `net46` framework, otherwise they won't be used by your function (which till target that framework only).

I hope this helps!